# Linux, re-route all outgoing traffic to a specfic IP

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I want to re-route all  out-going traffic (including UDP, TCP and ICMP) to a specific IP. More specifically,  I am creating a virtual interface using ifconfig, and I wont to reroute all traffic (UDP, TCP, ICMP etc..)  from the physical interface (eth0) to  the virtual interface  (eth0:0).  In essence, I am creating a proxy.

can this be done with iptables?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Michael Hampton I am creating a virtual interface using ifconfig, and I wont to reroute all traffic (UDP, TCP, ICMP etc..)  from the physical interface i.e (eth0) to  the virtual interface  (eth0:0).  In essence, I am creating a proxy.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "virtual interface". If you create an "eth0:0" the IP address is actually added to eth0. eth0:0 cannot be used as if it were a separate interface. The reason you see it that way is you are using the obsolete `ifconfig` tool, which presents it that way for historical reasons. With that out of the way, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Michael Hampton, Thanks for the clarification,  I want to create a proxy  that is part of the host. I.e: create a service  on machine A and redirect all outgoing network traffic from machine A to  this service. Is this possible?